# What does the "optional" parameter in AddJsonFile do?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am using [AddJsonFile method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.jsonconfigurationextensions.addjsonfile?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1&viewFallbackFrom=netcore-2.2) to add the correct appsettings files to my configuration. The method has an `bool optional` parameter that decides "whether the file is optional."

What does that mean, exactly? How will the app behave differently if the setting is enabled or disabled? What would be examples of where it needs to be set to true and false?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All it does is throw an exception on startup if you specify `false` and the file's not there (which is the default, for the method that doesn't take the parameter). It's entirely up to you when you'd want this, but typically, it helps guard against accidentally deleting or forgetting to copy a file with settings that you couldn't guess and don't all have defaults -- a (documented) configuration file is its own reward. Conversely, optional files would be used to specify overrides (in a read-write location) that need not be present; think shared file with global settings and a per-user override. (For things like websites this is obviously not as relevant, but you could still have an "administrator" config file with defaults and a "deployment specific" file with tunable settings.)

Comment: I have appsettings files for Dev, Stage, and Prod environments, along with a regular appsettings.js file. The regular file holds values that are common among all environments, and the environment-based files hold additional data specific to its environment. In order for the app to work it must use one of the environmental files along with the regular file. As I understand in my case, it makes sense to make all appsettings files `optional: false`?

Comment: I didn't find that it throws. Not sure it has any effect, but perhaps my unit test and understanding are incomplete.